# CSS Positioning, floats may be necessary

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to make this layout format as part of my intro level class to HTML/CSS. Can anyone help? Much appreciated.

See the attached link.[Probably can be created with mostly Divs. I tried to do divs with **widths of 100%** for the top and bottom sections. I'll probably do divs for the sidebar. How would I make the circles?

[image]

Comment: Well nobody is just going to do your assignment for you here. If you have a more specific problem though, post your code and describe the issue and someone might be able to help.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to this platform

Answer (score 0):

Answering the only question I see above…

You can make the “circles” by rounding elements (for example `<div>`s) with a CSS rule that applies `border-radius` on that element.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

```css
#wazzzzzzup {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: dodgerblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#wazzzzzzzzzzup {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gold;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#wazzup {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: orangered;
  border-radius: 100px / 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wazzzzzzup"></div>
<div id="wazzzzzzzzzzup"></div>
<div id="wazzup"></div>
```